# Cognos crosstab columns not resizing

Tags: cognos-10

I have this report in Cognos 10 Report Studio:[image]

The client wants the first column to be wider.  I go to the properties and set the size of the first column to 500 pixels and see this in Report Studio:[image]

But when I run the report, nothing has changed.  I've tried changing this several times and get the same results.  Is there something I'm missing?  Maybe not going high enough in the hierarchy to apply my change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Cognos doesn't play nice with browsers that aren't IE.

Answer (score 1):

The process is correct , i think you should try with a greater size in order to see the change.Just select the required column and change the size under size and overflow.

thanks,
Satarupa